# PyLucene Custom TokenStream using PythonTokenStream

Tags: python, lucene, pylucene

I am attempting to build a TokenStream from a Python Sequence.
Just for fun I want to be able to pass my own Tokens directly to

```
pylucene.Field("MyField", MyTokenStream)
```

I tried to make "MyTokenStream" by...

```
terms = ['pant', 'on', 'ground', 'look', 'like', 'fool']
stream = pylucene.PythonTokenStream()
for t in terms:
  stream.addAttribute(pylucene.TermAttribute(t))
```

But unfortunately a wrapper for "TermAttribute" doesn't exist, or for that matter any of the other `Attribute` classes in lucene so I get a NotImplemented error when calling them.

This doesn't raise an exception - but I'm not not sure if it's even setting the terms.

```
PythonTokenStream(terms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python* classes are designed to customize behavior by subclassing.  In the case of TokenStream, the incrementToken method needs to be overridden.

```
class MyTokenStream(lucene.PythonTokenStream):
    def __init__(self, terms):
        lucene.PythonTokenStream.__init__(self)
        self.terms = iter(terms)
        self.addAttribute(lucene.TermAttribute.class_)
    def incrementToken(self):
        for term in self.terms:
            self.getAttribute(lucene.TermAttribute.class_).setTermBuffer(term)
            return True
        return False

mts = MyTokenStream(['pant', 'on', 'ground', 'look', 'like', 'fool'])
while mts.incrementToken():
    print mts

<MyTokenStream: (pant)>
<MyTokenStream: (on)>
<MyTokenStream: (ground)>
<MyTokenStream: (look)>
<MyTokenStream: (like)>
<MyTokenStream: (fool)>
```

The result of addAttribute could also be stored, obviating the need for getAttribute.  My [lupyne](http://code.google.com/p/lupyne/) project has an [example](http://packages.python.org/lupyne/_modules/lupyne/engine/indexers.html#TokenFilter) of that.